# How does gradient descent weight/bias update work here?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, gradient-descent

I've been learning neural networks from Michael Nielsen's http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html.

In the section below to update the weights and biases

```
def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]

    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)

        #Zero vectors
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]

    self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]



def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
        test_data=None):
    if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
    n = len(training_data)
    for j in xrange(epochs):
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        mini_batches = [
            training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
            for k in xrange(0, n, mini_batch_size)]

        ####
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
        if test_data:
            print "Epoch {0}: {1} / {2}".format(
                j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test)
        else:
            print "Epoch {0} complete".format(j)
```

what is the need to introduce **nabla_b** and **nabla_w** zero vectors? when they're simply being added to the dnb and dnw which are numpy arrays themselves. Isn't 0 + something = something. What is the need for zero vector here for a single training example?

As a test I removed the zero vector and had dnb and dnw by itself and I failed to see any significant difference in the training.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right `0 + something = something`, but in the second iteration, it will be

```
something +something_else = value
```

So, this happens in the  following code
`for x, y in mini_batch:`

Here, for the first `minibatch` `nabla_w`,`nabla_b` will be 0, but for the second and later iterations, it will have some value.

lets consider the following code

```
nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
```

in the first iteration both `nabla_b` and `nabla_w` are zero's.
but, in this iteration, these are updated because of `nb+dnb` and so, nabla_b and nabla_w are no longer just vectors with just zeros.  so, in the second iteration, nabla_b is no longer a zero vector

Comment: I understand, here x, y = [ vector, value ] and update_mini_batch gets called like 

for mini_batch in mini_batches:
       self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch) 

For every training example, it initiates the zero vector.

Comment: sorry?, your doubt was about the use of zero vectors right?

Comment: I understand now so according to that a mini batch looks like say
"""  [ [V1, 3], [V2, 4] , [V3, 1] ]  """ .. how does for loop work in this ? for x, y ?
Wouldn't that make more sense in something like [ V1, 3 ] etc?

Comment: mini batch will be exactly as you said, but, its in for loop, so, in each iteration we will be getting one value of it. in the case of first iteration it will be [V1,3]. but, there it was kept as x,y in mini_batch, which will make, x=v1 and y=3 in the first iteration. the values simply unpack.

Comment: Damn I just realized. I feel extremely stupid. Thank you very much !

Comment: Great. That's a very good tutorial to get started. Do complete it